# SSL authentication, how to get the certificate information returned by the server

Tags: ssl

I am working on a program to monitor whether the server certificate is expired. How should the client initiate a request to the server in order to obtain the certificate returned by the server to the client?

Comment: This certificate is needed because it contains a lot of information, such as the issuing authority of the certificate, the expiration time, I need this expiration time

Comment: There is an edit button for a reason. Do not add information as comments. Instead, use the EDIT button and make your question better, more compete.

Answer (score 0):

From the article
[Check the expiration date of a SSL certificate](https://techdocs.akamai.com/eaa-gmbo/docs/check-expiration-date-ssl-cert) :

> You can check the expiration of the certificate (for example to help
> troubleshoot certificate issues).
>
> 1. Open a UNIX command line window.
> 2. Enter a query `openssl s_client -servername <NAME> -connect <HOST:PORT> 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates`.
>
> The expiration date appears in the response as
> `notAfter=<expiration_date>`.
>
> For example, if the HOSTis `control.akamai.com`, `PORT` is `443`,
> using the `openssl` command, you can see the expiration date is `Nov 21, 23:59:59 minutes in 2021`.